# Added Chart Data Values to Gauge Chart Areas

Tags: chart.js

I have this JavaScript ChartJS Chart. It renders a gauge chart, but i am having trouble getting the values to render within the two different areas of the chart

```
  var options = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["Per Post"],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [8000, 27000],
        backgroundColor: ["#ff0084","#000524"],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      rotation: 270, // start angle in degrees
      circumference: 180, // sweep angle in degrees
      plugins: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'per user', 
            position: 'bottom', // Positioning the chart title below the chart
            align: 'center', // Aligning the chart title to the center
            fontSize: 20, // Font size of the chart title
            color: 'white',
            padding: {
                top: -10 // Padding on the top side to move the title up
              }
          },
          legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'top', // Positioning the legend below the chart
            align: 'center', // Aligning the legend to the center
            labels: {
              boxWidth: 20, // Width of each legend box
              usePointStyle: true, // Using point style for legend boxes
              color: 'white' // Font color of the legend items
            }
          }      
      }
    }
  }
  
  var chart8ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer8').getContext('2d');
  new Chart(chart8ctx, options);
```

I've tried som many variations, but just cannot get it working. Hoping someone can help

Thanks

Comment: First thing to do, make sure that `labels` has the same number of entries as `data`.